# how to join two text files in python

Tags: python

i have two text files like 
`['i', 'hate', 'sausages', 'noa', 'hate', 'i']`

and then a numbers file

1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1

now i need to try and join the two files to each other

this is what i have so far

```
positionlist=open('positions.txt', 'r')#opening the code files with the postions

wordlist=open('Words.txt', 'r')#opening the word files 

positions = positionslist.read() #the code is reading the file to see what it is in the txt and is saving them as a vairable    
words = wordslist.read() #the code is reading the file to see what it is in the txt and is  saving them as a vairable  

print(positions) #prints the positions
print(words)     #prints the words 
positionfinal = list(positions) # makes the postions into a list

#this is where i need to tey and connect the two codes together 

remover = words.replace("[","") #replacing the brackes withnothing so that it is red like a string
remover = remover.replace("]","")#replacing the brackes withnothing so that it is red like a string
```

Comment: What do you want the output of this "join" to be?

Comment: just for every number to be in line with it word

Comment: It would be much clearer if, in the question itself, you provided an example of your desired output.

Comment: It looks like you have a JSON file as an input, just with .txt extension

Comment: so i really want to create a vairable or a text file that will store the words and numbers together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the input files looks like it's Python literals (list of strings, tuple of integers), so you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse it. And then you can use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to loop through them together and print them out. Something like this:

```
import ast

with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = ast.literal_eval(f.read())  # read as list of strings

with open('positions.txt') as f:
    positions = ast.literal_eval(f.read())  # read as tuple of ints

for position, word in zip(positions, words):
    print(position, word)
```

Here's the output:

```
1 i
2 hate
3 sausages
3 noa
2 hate
1 i
```